# How can I use .htaccess to hide extension and prevent user access with extension url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here is my code for hide .html  and .php extension when user view my site, `http://example.com/xxx.html` to `http://example.com/xxx`
But I hope to make user when they input `http://example.com/xxx.html`, they cannnot access and jump to 404 not found.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# Remove .html-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
 </IfModule>
```

Anyone have solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this as your first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(?:html|php)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

**Update**

Perhaps this will fix your `ErrorDocument` problem:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(?:html|php)\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/error404.html
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Seems ok, but I had used .htaccess to change the error 404 to /error404.html, like this `ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html` As you said, the RewriteRule will redirect to 404 not found. But in this case, I input `http://example.com/xxx.html` will not redirect to /error404.html. It shows another 404 page (may be default one, but not actually same as default one). It said "The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: I added an update, as it seems that perhaps the 404 error is getting a 404 from the same rule.

Comment: Thanks, it's work! Another question, how to prevent user visit for example `http://example.com/index/` cause it will make the images and assets linking not work. Hope to block the word `index` by rewrite, and redirect to /error404.html. Special thanks!

Comment: I think that needs another question Samson, it needs looking at properly. Glad it worked for you.